# How to get the child from a parent in a parent child relationship for realm in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

What i am trying to do is access a child when I have the parent in realm. In this example I have a simple table view that I want to populate with the child when accessing the parent. The part I am struggling with is trying to find the child when accessing the parent.

This is the viewController that i am trying to access the children:

```
import UIKit
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class OtherViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var otherTableView: UITableView!

    var realm: Realm!
    var realmedData = ""

    var realmList: Results<Realmed> {
        get {
            return realm.objects(Realmed.self)
        }
    }


    var realmTwoList: Results<RealmTwo> {
        get {
            return realm.objects(RealmTwo.self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        realm = try! Realm()
        self.otherTableView.delegate = self
        self.otherTableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var counted = realm.objects(RealmTwo.self).filter("realmLbl == %@", realmedData)
        return counted.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherTableViewCell

        var celledItem = realm.objects(Realmed.self)
        for item in celledItem {
            for items in item.realmTwo {
                cell.otherLbl.text = "\(items.spanish)"
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

this is another method I tried for the cell for row at:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherTableViewCell

    var celledItem = realm.objects(Realmed.self)
    for item in celledItem {
        for items in item.realmTwo {
            cell.otherLbl.text = "\(items.spanish)"
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

this is the parent realm class:

```
import Foundation
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class Realmed: Object {
    @objc dynamic var label = ""
    @objc dynamic var romanNum = ""
    @objc dynamic var txt = ""
    let realmTwo = List<RealmTwo>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "label"
    }


    convenience init(label: String, romanNum: String, txt: String) {
        self.init()
        self.label = label
        self.romanNum = romanNum
        self.txt = txt
    }

}
```

and this is the realm class for the child:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class RealmTwo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var realmLbl = String()
    @objc dynamic var spanish = String()
    @objc dynamic var french = String()
    let realmed = LinkingObjects(fromType: Realmed.self, property: "realmTwo")



    convenience init(realmLbl: String, spanish: String, french: String) {
        self.init()
        self.realmLbl = realmLbl
        self.spanish = spanish
        self.french = french
    }

}
```

When I run this as is, the only thing that populates the tableview is the last value saved to realm. 
In this example the children are the strings: "Uno" and "Un", and I want them both to populate the tableView, but the tableView is only populated by the last value in realm, in this case, "Un". 
Through research I found out that it is because I am looping through the realm value to get the child. The problem with that is that the only way to get to the child is with the loop but then it can't populate a tableView. It seems like a lose-lose situation.

What I am curious about is how to access the child when you have a parent in realm so that I am able to populate a tableView.

If you need anything please ask. Thank you

Comment: In your tableView(_:cellForRowAt:), you are accessing RealmTwo's "spanish" property only. Don't you want to access its "french" property as well?

Comment: I do but that isn’t the problem right now. I’m more worried about looping around a list in a table view

Comment: You are really not going to want present data this way. It's going to be super laggy and frustrating for your user. Every time the tableView is reloaded, it pulling data 'from disk' and filtering, and that's inherently slower than accessing that data from an array. When the view loads, populate your tableView dataSource, typically an array, with the data from Realm and then use the dataSource (array) to populate the tableView. That will also simplify your code as when the tableView needs to populate a cell, get it from the array *let object = myArray[index]* and then cell.text = object.french.

Comment: I thought about that but how do I access the child from that. At the top of the view controller I have an array to try and populate the table view but when ever I try and use it I get everything in that realm database. I just want the one that has the specific to the label selected.

Comment: Is this a situation where you have a master-Detail? So you've got a list in one view and you are tapping on an item and want to display the child data in another view? Oh - and when you respond here in comments, add an @ in front of their name so they will know you responded. @NEWBY

Comment: @Jay. Thank you still new at this. That is exactly what I am doing. It is basically a view with a saved value and I successfully created a child, I just have trouble accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

i think I got something. I figured that what I needed was an array, and it seems that it is unwise to change List to an Array, so what i did was get the content from the List and put it in an array, since it is easier to put data in a tableview from an array.

This is the array that i created:

```
var realmArr = [String]()
```

and this is the cell for row at for the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherTableViewCell

    var celledItem = realm.objects(Realmed.self)
    for item in celledItem {
        for items in item.realmTwo {
            self.realmArr.append(items.spanish)
        }
    }

    cell.otherLbl.text = "\(realmArr[indexPath.row])"
    return cell
    }
```

I am not sure if this is okay, but it is the only thing that I can think of.
Thank you for all the help.

Comment: There's no reason to change the Realm Results into an array. Realm Results were actually designed to function like and array and can safely be used as your tableView datasource.

Comment: @Jay, i understand that but when i try and access the Realm Results in any other way it only gets the last result that is saved to realm. Wouldn't it be easier to put data from an array into a tableview than a realm result.

Comment: See my answer. The results work quite well and in my answer not only do we populate the tableView with it, we also use the Results to get a specific PersonClass object and therefore it's child DogClass property.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address this at a high level with a few code snippets. The question is using Objects so let's take a more concrete example of Person and Dog. In this example we have a list of Person Objects each one owning one dog. So we have a single direction relationship

First we have a Person and Dog class

```
class DogClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
}

class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var dog: DogClass?
}
```

Here's a viewController class that contains a tableView of people

```
class peopleVC: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var peopleResults: Results<PersonClass>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let realm = RealmService //or however you talk to your realm
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.peopleResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self) //loads Person objects
        self.tableView.reloadData() //shows the list
    }
```

and within that class, the tableView delegate methods that populate our tableview and handle a tap on a row

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return peopleResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    let person = self.peopleResults[row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = person.name

    return cell
}

   //when a row is tapped we need to determine the row, which will be included
   // in the indexPath property with indexPath.row
   // From there get the object from the dataSource array via it's row index
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let person = self.peopleResults[row]
        let dog = person.dog

        //at this point you have the dog object and you could print the name
        print(dog.name)

       //or pass it to a detail view via a segue etc

    }
```

Comment: where did you get Person in the variable:  Results<Person>!. Also i tried doing something like that and what you are doing is populating the parent in the tableview. In my example and question i am trying to find the child.

Comment: @NEWBY Oops - that was a typo but you should get the idea. It supposed to be PersonClass. You are trying to find a child of the parent class, which is DogClass. That's the bottom part of the example - once you tap a row, retrieve the PersonClass object so you can then get its child DogClass object. See the code.